# Using SignalR to display row by row processing of Excel fileUpload

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asyncfileupload

I am trying to figure out how can i use FileUpload along with signalR where i can start processing the uploaded Excel file row by row(without waiting for the file to be fully uploaded).

So i have a large(could be upto 2GB, but consider on average to be 100 mb) Excel file being uploaded, i want to start display the progress in Percentage as well as display all the rows that were processed and if any error occurred during the processing of that row.

Any links to an article will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a decoupled message bus proxy (Eventaggregator proxy) for SignalR.
This fits your use case perfectly, in your case I would fire events while processsing the file. This will be automatically forwarded to the cients, you can also constraint so that only the user that uploaded the file will see events generated by that file upload.

Please check this blog post I made for a insight into the library

http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/

Demo
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4